# Can Composite Reliability (CR) be used for attenuation correction in meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, composite

I'm trying to conduct a meta-analysis on correlation using Spearman's disattenuation formula: rx'y' = rxy/sqrt(rxx*ryy). **Can composite reliability (CR) instead of Cronbach's α be used in this formula**? Since some studies only reported CR instead of Cronbach's α.

**Or can CR be transferred to Cronbach's α?** I searched it online but didn't find any formula for that.

Answer (score 1):

Composite reliability is a general term. Cronbach's alpha is one specific type of composite reliability coefficient that is appropriate when a composite/sum score is composed of essentially or strictly tau-equivalent measures as defined in classical test theory. For other types of measures, other types of composite reliability coefficients are available (e.g., McDonald's omega for congeneric measures; Spearman-Brown coefficient for essentially or strictly tau-parallel measures). Any of these composite reliability coefficients can be used if it is appropriate given the nature of the variables (i.e., depending on whether they are tau-parallel, tau-equivalent, or congeneric).

Note that Cronbach's alpha can lead to an underestimation of reliability when the measures are "only" congeneric (but not tau-equivalent). This would then lead to an "overcorrection" of the observed correlation and an overestimation of the latent (true score) correlation. Cronbach's alpha is often misapplied (i.e., it is not tested whether the measures satisfy the rather strict conditions of tau equivalence). For congeneric measures or measures that are multidimensional (measure more than one factor), Cronbach's alpha is not appropriate for estimating composite reliability.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Dr. Geiser. You mentioned that "Cronbach's alpha can lead to an underestimation of reliability when the measures are "only" congeneric (but not tau-equivalent)", does that mean Cronbach's alpha should be the only type of reliability to be applied in the formula?

Comment: It means that you should not use Cronbach's alpha when your items aren't in line with the measurement model of (essential) tau equivalence. That is, when the items measure more than one factor and/or when they differ in their loadings on a single factor, Cronbach's alpha may underestimate composite reliability, leading to an overestimation of the latent correlation in the correction for attenuation formula.

Comment: You should use whichever composite reliability formula is appropriate given then nature/psychometric properties of the items. It does not necessarily have to be Cronbach's alpha.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration, it helps a lot.